# Bootstrap Carousel not changing slides

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I am trying to build a carousel using bootstrap and am using one of the templates. However, the slides don't change when I click the next and previous arrow buttons, and it will transition on it's own to slide 2 after an incorrect interval, but never to slide 3. I don't know what the issue is because I have included both jquery.js and boostrap.js with the correct file paths.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 1000
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Calling jquery first -->
<script language="JavaScript" type="module" type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/jquery/src/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="module" type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--Carousel-->
<script type="module" src="./assets/js/main.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="mainCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#mainCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#mainCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#mainCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="./assets/images/one.png" alt="First slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h2>First Slide Label</h2>
            <p>Text for the first slide</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="./assets/images/two.png" alt="Second slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Second Slide Label</h5>
            <p>Text for second slide</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="./assets/images/three.png" alt="Third slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Third Slide Label</h5>
            <p>Text for third slide</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#mainCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#mainCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, the `language` attribute is long [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script). Also, since there's no way to debug your example I'm afraid this question will not attract the so-needed answerer.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the bootstrap CSS is being called within the head element, and make sure to load all script tags before the body closing tag to ensure that it the javascript gets loaded after the site's UI is rendered. This is to avoid loading speed. Also make sure your not overriding any CSS from bootstrap as that is very common.

If none of the above work, please share a github link and ill happilly look over at the code and troubleshoot it with you.

video link on how i did it: https://www.loom.com/share/9254958ffcd54e49b82cb4b7bd5400c7

and the link to view the code: https://codepen.io/solit0123/pen/qBoyrpG

Here is a carousel I made with bootstrap specifically for you:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bd-example">
    <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Second slide label</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Third slide label</h5>
            <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

add this script tag before closing body tag.